# Positioning of getElementById in HTML&Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a small game with multiple choices in Javascript, after I choose the answers and hit submit, at the bottom, it will show the answer of how many questions I answer correctly, and incorrectly as "You got question 1 correct", or "You got question 2 wrong".  However, I'm not able to get the "You got question "" right/wrong in the position right after "Correct/Wrong Answer:".  But when I tried the method of showing the score, it does work.  Can someone point me a direction please?  Thank you for your time of reading my post.

```js
var firstQuestion = document.getElementsByName("firstQuestion");
            var secondQuestion = document.getElementsByName("secondQuestion");
            var thirdQuestion = document.getElementsByName("thirdQuestion");
            var myArr = [firstQuestion, secondQuestion, thirdQuestion];
            var score = 0;
            var score2 = 0;
            var score3 = 0;
            var firstPara = document.getElementById("firstPara");
            var secondPara = document. getElementById("secondPara");

            function submitted() {
            //for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                for(var o = 0; o < firstQuestion.length; o++) {
                    var num = o+1;
                    var name= "choice" + num ;
                        if ((document.getElementById(name).getAttribute("value") =="true") && (document.getElementById(name).checked))
                        {
                            score++;
                            $("#correctScore").text(score);
                            document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML + "You got question 1 right!<br>";
                            break;

                        }
                }
                if(score==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML + "You got question 1 wrong!<br>";;
                }
                
                //question 2
                for(var o = 3; o < secondQuestion.length + 3; o++) {
                    var num = o+1;
                    var name= "choice" + num ;
                        if ((document.getElementById(name).getAttribute("value") =="true") && (document.getElementById(name).checked))
                        {
                            score++;
                            score2++;
                            $("#correctScore").text(score);
                            document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML + "You got question 2 right!<br>";
                            break;

                        }
                }
                if(score2==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML + "You got question 2 wrong!<br>";;
                }

                //question 3
                for(var o = 6; o < thirdQuestion.length + 6; o++) {
                    var num = o+1;
                    var name= "choice" + num ;
                        if ((document.getElementById(name).getAttribute("value") =="true") && (document.getElementById(name).checked))
                        {
                            score++;
                            score3++;
                            $("#correctScore").text(score);
                            document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("firstPara").innerHTML + "You got question 3 right!<br>";
                            break;

                        }
                }
                if(score3==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML =document.getElementById("secondPara").innerHTML + "You got question 3 wrong!<br>";;
                    $("#correctScore").text=0;
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="timeRemaining">
                <p>Time Remaining:
                    <span id="timer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="image" id="startBtn" src="assets/images/start.jpg" value="click me"/> 

        <br>
        

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
            <div class="questions">
                What is the name of Black Panther's home?
                </br>
                <input id="choice1" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false"><small>K'un Lun</small>
                <input id="choice2" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="true"><small>Wakanda</small>
                <input id="choice3" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false"><small>Kamar Taj</small>
                <br>
                <br>
                How did Dr Strange defeat Dormammu?</br>
                <input id="choice4" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false"><small>Built An Energy Prison</small></input>
                <input id="choice5" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="true"><small>Create a Time Loop</small></input>
                <input id="choice6" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false"><small>Froze Time</small></input>
                <br>
                <br>
                Which hero secretly has a family?</br>
                <input id="choice7" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="true"><small>Hawkeye</small></input>
                <input id="choice8" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false"><small>Wakanda</small></input>
                <input id="choice9" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false"><small>Kamar Taj</small></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitted()"/>
            </div>

            
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="answerScreen">
                <div class="splashBox2">
                    <h2>Let's see how you did</h2>
                <hr/>
                    <p id="correctScreen">Correct Answers: 
                        <span id="correctScore"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p id="firstPara" style="font-size: 20;color: azure;margin-left: 60%;"></p>
                    <p id="wrongScreen">Wrong Answers: 
                        <span id="wrongScore"></span>
                    </p>
                    <p id="secondPara" style="font-size: 20;color: azure; margin-left: 60%;"></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the position right after". And also what "the method of showing the score" is and how you can tell that it worked?

Comment: Thank you for reading my post Cat.  I took a screenshot of the game result, at the bottom, there's a section called "Correct Answers: ", once I hit submit, I would like the "You got question 1 right" lined up with "Correct Answers:", which is where the score number 2 is right now.  I don't want to show the score "2", but I'm having trouble of making "You got question 1 right" where the score "2" is.  I set a var in my js with score++, when the answer is correct, it counts how many questions that I answer correctly.  I apologize that I didn't explain it clearly when I posted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your clarification and perusing your code, here's what I can suggest.

```
<p id="correctScreen">Correct Answers:<span id="correctScore"></span></p>
<p id="" style="font-size: 20;color: azure;margin-left: 60%;"></p>
<p id="wrongScreen">Wrong Answers:<span id="wrongScore"></span></p>
<p id="secondPara" style="font-size: 20;color: azure; margin-left: 60%;"></p>
```

The correctScore span is where you want your "You got..." text to appear, and you could accomplish this by simply replacing `$("#correctScore").text(score);` with `$("#correctScore").text("You got question 1 right");` (And obviously you'd want to rename your elements and variables so they make sense with the replacement.)

The only issue is that the next line of text (the text for question 2) would be vertically aligned with "Correct answers" instead of with the question 1 text. The simplest way to fix this (and not really a professional way) would be to add a bunch of `&nbsp` characters to indent your text. Below are some other (better) options.

Using just HTML markup, you could replace the span with a block element, like a `div` (and change your `correctScreen` from being a `p` to being a `div` to make this work). The catch is that switching to a block element also means the contents would start on a new line, so they wouldn't be next to "Correct answers:" as you would like -- unless you styled the block element with `float: left` (and made the other changes that go along with this, such as specifying a width attribute for your divs.)

Or since your page has bootstrap, you could avoid handling (some of) these details yourself and get two divs to appear side-by-side by doing something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="spacer"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="correctAnswersIntro">Correct answers:</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="correctAnswersList">You got question 1 right<br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cat, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issue that is needed to be corrected in your code.

Firstly, the JavaScript snippet has a syntax error, where the last brace is missing. I assume that it's a mistake while copying it here.

Secondly, you are using the mix of JavaScript API and jQuery to access DOM elements. If you stick to one, it will be cleaner and the code will be easier to read. Please see below.

...

```
var firstQuestion = $('[name="firstQuestion"]');
var secondQuestion = $('[name="seconQuestion"]');
var thirdQuestion = $('[name="thirdQuestion"]');;

var score = 0;
var score2 = 0;
var score3 = 0;
var firstPara = $("#firstPara");
var secondPara = $("#secondPara");

function submitted() {

    for (var o = 0; o < firstQuestion.length; o++) {
        var num = o + 1;
        var name = "choice" + num;
        if (($('#' + name).getAttribute("value") == "true") && ($('#' + name).checked))
        {
            score++;
            $("#correctScore").text(score);
            $("#firstPara").html($("#firstPara").html() + "You got question 1 right!<br>");
            break;

        }
    }
    if (score == 0)
    {
        $("#secondPara").html($("#secondPara").html() + "You got question 1 wrong!<br>");
    }

    //question 2
    for (var o = 3; o < secondQuestion.length + 3; o++) {
        var num = o + 1;
        var name = "choice" + num;
        if (($('#' + name).getAttribute("value") == "true") && ($('#' + name).checked))
        {
            score++;
            score2++;
            $("#correctScore").text(score);
            $("#firstPara").html($("#firstPara").html() + "You got question 2 right!<br>");
            break;

        }
    }
    if (score2 == 0)
    {
        $("#secondPara").html($("#secondPara").html() + "You got question 2 wrong!<br>");
        ;
    }

    //question 3
    for (var o = 6; o < thirdQuestion.length + 6; o++) {
        var num = o + 1;
        var name = "choice" + num;
        if (($('#' + name).getAttribute("value") == "true") && ($('#' + name).checked))
        {
            score++;
            score3++;
            $("#correctScore").text(score);
            $("#firstPara").html($("#firstPara").html() + "You got question 3 right!<br>");
            break;

        }
    }
    if (score3 == 0)
    {
        $("#secondPara").html($("#secondPara").html() + "You got question 3 wrong!<br>");
        ;
        $("#correctScore").text(0);
    }
}
```

...

Please post the full HTML code here, so that it would be easier to correct it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your pointer, I really appreciate it, will try to revise it and improve it, I have reposted my html :)